# Create php with a jQuery and php include

Tags: php, jquery

Well, I've created a code to include a PHP page in a box and not only the normal `include ('');`

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var count = 1;
            $('#append').click(function() {
                if (count < 2) {
                    $('#parent').append('<div id="first' + count + '">text</div>');
                    $('#first1').load('../image/index.php');
                    count++;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <a id="append">Add DIV 1</a>
    <div id="parent">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I've noticed I could "load" a page in html, but all the php and javascript code is "out".
How do I do to have the "real" page inside another.

Comment: `$.get()` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code is not returned since it is executed on the server before you get the HTML back from it.
In order to just retrieve it as plain text you will need to change the file you are trying to retrieve.

As far as how to load a page inside another page, you can use iframes for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  var count = 1;
  $('#append').click(function(){
      if (count <2){
         $('#parent').append('<div id="first'+count+'">text</div>');
         $.get('http://test.com/image/index.php',function(data){
             $('#first1').html(data);
         });
         count++;
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: in the case, the output will be "/image/index.php" and not the page itself

Comment: Does index.php echo any content?